# 2013 Advanced Search Page Lost Scope Picker

Tags: 2013, result-source, advanced-search

I'm doing an upgrade from 2010 to 2013 and have found that the ability to put a scope selector on the advanced search page is no longer present.  This is a strict requirement so I need to find a way to get around this.  Assuming I've created the necessary result sources, does anyone know a way to have them listed as option on the advanced search page like it was in 2010?

Even if the presentation is different, I really just need a way for users to have the option of making the selection, which essentially limits the search to specific site collections.  I'm getting murdered on this one so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this problem? I am also facing same problem.